# dBeaver (CE): DB2 LUW Connection with SQL ERROR 42704. Table Schema won't open but able to write SQL queries

Tags: db2, zos, dbeaver

After about a year and half, I am finally able to connect to the DB2 database we have through dBeaver. The connection is successful as a LUW (Our db2 is z/os). I was able to get the drivers required after installing IBM Data Studio.

Once I am connected, I go down the schema, get to Tables, and on clicking that, I get the below error.

```
SQL Error [42704]: SYSCAT.SCHEMATA IS AN UNDEFINED NAME. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=3.69.56
SYSCAT.SCHEMATA IS AN UNDEFINED NAME. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=3.69.56
THE DESCRIBE STATEMENT DOES NOT SPECIFY A PREPARED STATEMENT. SQLCODE=-516, SQLSTATE=26501, DRIVER=3.69.56
THE CURSOR SQL_CURLH200C1 IS NOT IN A PREPARED STATE. SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, DRIVER=3.69.56
SQL Error [42704]: SYSCAT.SCHEMATA IS AN UNDEFINED NAME. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=3.69.56
```

However, if ignore the error and go to New SQL query and write a simple

```
Select * from schema.table
```

it works fine and get the results I want.

Considering the time i have spent to get till here, this is sufficient, but to deploy as a solution in my department, I need to be able to look at a Table List (schema).

Any help would be awesome.

EDIT1: What the issue is here, is that there is no SCHEMA with the name SYSCAT and no table named SCHEMATA.

Comment: I assume your using the db2java.zip class file that is shipped with the Db2 version on z/OS ?   Can you confirm where you got the driver from ?

Comment: Our IT sucks....and i can't emphasize that enough. I provided them exactly what I needed and they were still lost. After a lot of searching, and after installing IBM Data Studio, i was able to find both the driver files I need. I am non IT btw. Here are the 2 files I am using as drivers: db2jcc.jar and db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar. Not sure if that answers your question

Comment: See my answer below ... I think this answers the question.  Its a driver issue.  If you need further assistance comment back.

Comment: You can download the data server drivers from here https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878. The ones in Data Studio are the same but maybe not the latest fix level

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The z/OS Db2 catalog has different names than the ones used on Db2 on distributed (Linux Unix Windows aka LUW).  Here is a [list of objects on Db2 z/OS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/cattab/src/tpc/db2z_catalogtablesintro.html) that you can review.

It looks like you are using dBeaver to navigate through a UI the objects on Db2 for z/OS.  You will need to ensure you have a db2 jcc driver that is for z/OS Db2.  It looks like you may be using one from LUW as the SYSCAT.SCHEMATA is an LUW object, not a z/OS object.

Your other query works because you are specifying a known table name.  Other queries should be fine.  The issue is the interface in dbeaver is looking at Db2 system objects for LUW and not z/OS.  This will continue until you are able to resolve the driver issue.

Comment: You are awesome. After looking at your solution, and as i mentioned initially, I did use LUW for connection. I was unable to find z/os as an option under the DB2 connection setup. I used the search bar and typed the same and then out of no where, got the option. Once I added the information, changed the driver from MS Access to DB2, referenced the same 2 drivers I mentioned above, and then on the main screen, changed the required Database/Schema to just Database ignoring the schema, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Awesome to hear its fixed.  Having ridden the distributed and z/OS paths I've been (un)fortunate enough to whack my head into a few walls :)

Answer (score 1):

The IBM Data Server Drivers also require server sided set-up.  Please see this information https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_jccenablespsandtables.html

Comment: Is there a snippet of the linked page you can quote here? Links have a habit of breaking over time.

Answer (score 0):

In DBeaver, when you create a connection choose the "DB2 z/OS driver" option under the Db2 drop down, when connecting to DB2 for z/OS

BTW DBeaver can shell share with Data Studio, so you can (if you wish) use both products in one install. No guarantees that they share happily in all cases, but it appears to work reasonably well.